# Unable to connect Google forms to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an add-on that will send the questions and answer from the google forms to the real-time database. I found the following steps to be able to pass the forms data to [firebase](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase).

However, when following the steps, I get the following error (refer to the screenshot below). I am not sure if this library is no longer available. Is there another approach that I can try that will allow me to pass the data from google forms to firebase?

[image]

Comment: @CarlosM: Thank You. Yes, this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post: [Cannot add Firebase library to Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862681/cannot-add-firebase-library-to-apps-script):

You now need the script ID as opposed to the project key to install an Apps Script library. The script ID for this specific library is `1hguuh4Zx72XVC1Zldm_vTtcUUKUA6iBUOoGnJUWLfqDWx5WlOJHqYkrt`, which can also be seen in the [FirebaseApp](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/source) site.

**References:**

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)
- [Firebase](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)